# How to run Python Eve application on a different port

Tags: python, flask, eve

I'm trying to run this application on a different port(8080).  I tried putting the port parameter but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm getting a 404 page, but when i switch port to 5000, I encounter no problem.

```
from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

@app.route("/hello", methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: (venv)jiii@jiii-jump:~/www/eve2$ python run.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2014 11:52:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2014 11:53:09] "GET /people HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `SERVER_NAME = None` (which is the default) is set in your settings file.

Comment: thanks nicola!  I forgot to change the # SERVER_NAME = '127.0.0.1:5000'